# Full Calendar navigation links not showing

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to set up a Full Calendar that shows events from a public Google calendar. I have set up a test calendar and it is showing the events. However, the navlinks are not showing at all?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.print.css">
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.4.0/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.4.0/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/locale/fi.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/gcal.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {          
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
                left: 'prev,next,today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
            },
        weekNumbers: true,
        navLinks: true,
        googleCalendarApiKey: 'working api key here',
        events: {
            googleCalendarId: 'abc@group.calendar.google.com'
        }
    });
});
</script>
<title>
test calendar</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<div id='calendar'></div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `fullcalendar.print.css` then you have to add `media="print"` in the stylesheet, like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.print.css" media="print">
```

and the other option is that you can also remove this `fullcalendar.print.css` stylesheet from the page (but if you want to see the calendar on print screen as well then don't remove the `fullcalendar.print.css`)

Answer (score 2):

the issue that you had was simple just add this **media='print'** tp print stylesheet

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.print.css" >
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.print.css"  media='print'>
```